# Substutute for FacebookSubscriptionVerify in facebook C# SDk 6.4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, facebook-fql, facebook-c#-sdk

In latest version of Facebook C# SDk 6.4. Can we use `FacebookSubscriptionVerify` Action Method Attribute ? As this is not available in the `FacebookClient` Class

I was using the older version of Facebok C# SDK in my MVC3 project. Now, After switching to Facebook C# SDK 6.4 this class is not available.

Do we have any substitute for this?

Comment: How old of a version were you using?  Between versions 5 and 6, there was a major overhaul of the namespaces and available methods.  I am not familiar with the attribute that you mention, but just wanted to throw that out there

Answer (score 2):

I took a little more time this morning and confirmed that the attribute that you referenced was removed in version 6 (along with tons of other items).  Since this project is open source, here is the code for the `FacebookSubscriptionVerify` ActionFilter that you used to use.  For any references to functions within here that I did not include, this version on CodePlex has all of the code available for you to look at: http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/08cb51f372b5#Source/Facebook.Web/FacebookSubscriptionsHttpHandler.cs

The new version (version 6.X) and the last few branches of version 5 can be found on the GitHub site - https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-csharp-sdk/tree/master/Source

With the availability of the source code, you should be able to, in tandem with how you were using this function, create your own `ActionFilterAttribute` that can replicate the functionality that you had previously.

```
// --------------------------------
// <copyright file="FacebookSubscriptionVerifyAttribute.cs" company="Thuzi LLC (www.thuzi.com)">
//     Microsoft Public License (Ms-PL)
// </copyright>
// <author>Nathan Totten (ntotten.com), Jim Zimmerman (jimzimmerman.com) and Prabir Shrestha (prabir.me)</author>
// <license>Released under the terms of the Microsoft Public License (Ms-PL)</license>
// <website>http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com</website>
// ---------------------------------

namespace Facebook.Web.Mvc
{
using System.Web.Mvc;

public class FacebookSubscriptionVerifyAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public string VerificationToken { get; set; }

    public FacebookSubscriptionVerifyAttribute(string verificationToken)
    {
        VerificationToken = verificationToken;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        var request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;
        var modelState = filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState;

        string errorMessage;

        if (request.HttpMethod == "GET")
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(VerificationToken))
            {
                errorMessage = "Verification Token is empty.";
            }
            else
            {
                if (FacebookSubscriptionVerifier.VerifyGetSubscription(request, VerificationToken, out errorMessage))
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            errorMessage = "Invalid http method.";
        }

        modelState.AddModelError("facebook-subscription", errorMessage);

        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
    }
}
```

}

**And the code for the FacebookSubscriptionVerifier Class**

```
namespace Facebook.Web
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Diagnostics.Contracts;
    using System.Globalization;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Web;

    /// <summary>
    /// Facebook helper methods for web.
    /// </summary>
    internal static class FacebookSubscriptionVerifier
    {
        internal const string HTTP_X_HUB_SIGNATURE_KEY = "HTTP_X_HUB_SIGNATURE";

        internal static byte[] ComputeHmacSha1Hash(byte[] data, byte[] key)
        {
            Contract.Requires(data != null);
            Contract.Requires(key != null);
            Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<byte[]>() != null);

            using (var crypto = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA1(key))
            {
                return crypto.ComputeHash(data);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Verify HTTP_X_HUB_SIGNATURE.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="secret">
        /// The secret.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="httpXHubSignature">
        /// The http x hub signature.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="jsonString">
        /// The json string.
        /// </param>
        /// <returns>
        /// Returns true if validation is successful.
        /// </returns>
        internal static bool VerifyHttpXHubSignature(string secret, string httpXHubSignature, string jsonString)
        {
            Contract.Requires(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(secret));

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(httpXHubSignature) && httpXHubSignature.StartsWith("sha1=") && httpXHubSignature.Length > 5 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(jsonString))
            {
                // todo: test inner parts
                var expectedSignature = httpXHubSignature.Substring(5);

                var sha1 = ComputeHmacSha1Hash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString), Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secret));

                var hashString = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (var b in sha1)
                {
                    hashString.Append(b.ToString("x2"));
                }

                if (expectedSignature == hashString.ToString())
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Verify HTTP_X_HUB_SIGNATURE for http GET method.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="request">
        /// The http request.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="verifyToken">
        /// The verify token.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="errorMessage">
        /// The error message.
        /// </param>
        /// <returns>
        /// Returns true if successful otherwise false.
        /// </returns>
        internal static bool VerifyGetSubscription(HttpRequestBase request, string verifyToken, out string errorMessage)
        {
            Contract.Requires(request != null);
            Contract.Requires(request.HttpMethod == "GET");
            Contract.Requires(request.Params != null);
            Contract.Requires(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(verifyToken));

            errorMessage = null;

            if (request.Params["hub.mode"] == "subscribe")
            {
                if (request.Params["hub.verify_token"] == verifyToken)
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.Params["hub.challenge"]))
                    {
                        errorMessage = Properties.Resources.InvalidHubChallenge;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    errorMessage = Properties.Resources.InvalidVerifyToken;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                errorMessage = Properties.Resources.InvalidHubMode;
            }

            return false;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Verify HTTP_X_HUB_SIGNATURE for http POST method.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="request">
        /// The request.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="secret">
        /// The secret.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="jsonString">
        /// The json string.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="errorMessage">
        /// The error message.
        /// </param>
        /// <returns>
        /// Returns true if successful otherwise false.
        /// </returns>
        internal static bool VerifyPostSubscription(HttpRequestBase request, string secret, string jsonString, out string errorMessage)
        {
            Contract.Requires(request != null);
            Contract.Requires(request.HttpMethod == "POST");
            Contract.Requires(request.Params != null);
            Contract.Requires(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(secret));

            errorMessage = null;

            // signatures looks somewhat like "sha1=4594ae916543cece9de48e3289a5ab568f514b6a"
            var signature = request.Params["HTTP_X_HUB_SIGNATURE"];

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(signature) && signature.StartsWith("sha1="))
            {
                var expectedSha1 = signature.Substring(5);

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(expectedSha1))
                {
                    errorMessage = Properties.Resources.InvalidHttpXHubSignature;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(jsonString))
                    {
                        errorMessage = Properties.Resources.InvalidJsonString;
                        return false;
                    }

                    var sha1 = ComputeHmacSha1Hash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString), Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secret));

                    var hashString = new StringBuilder();
                    foreach (var b in sha1)
                    {
                        hashString.Append(b.ToString("x2"));
                    }

                    if (expectedSha1 == hashString.ToString())
                    {
                        // todo: test
                        return true;
                    }

                    // todo: test
                    errorMessage = Properties.Resources.InvalidHttpXHubSignature;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                errorMessage = Properties.Resources.InvalidHttpXHubSignature;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Facebook.Web.Mvc is dead now.

Comment: Yes...you are right, which is the "big differences" between 5 and 6 that I mentioned.  However, you wanted to know how to replace the functionality of that particular actionfilter attribute.  The best way to do that is to look at the code for the attribute and recreate it or find another way to do the same functions.  Of course, your comment could also be a realization of the direction the project took (saw you had a lot of questions around the new SDK v6) :D